# Creating a more efficient matrix transpose code in C

Tags: c, pointers, math, transpose

I am working on creating a more efficient version of this C code, by using pointer arithmetic but I'm stuck.

This is the original code:

(I'm calling my array type Marray_t, int M)

```
void transpose(Marray_t A){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        for(j=0; j<M; j++){
            int t = A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = A[j][i];
            A[j][i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

*Without using malloc*, I want to create a more efficient way of doing a transpose on a square matrix of dimension MxM.

This is what I was trying:

```
void transpose(Marray_t A, int M){
int i, j;
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
    int *row = A[i];
    for(j=0; j<M; j++){
    int *col = &A[i][j];
            int t1 = *(row+i); 
    int t2 = *(col + M*i)+(i*4);
    *row = t2;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run my code on a 2x2 matrix, it doesn't work.

If I have matrix = {{2,3},{4,5}}, my transpose should give me {{2,4},{3,5}}, but I get {{3,2},{4,5}}

I am very new to using pointers so any advice/help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: How can it possibly work, when the only elements you change are in the first column?

Comment: Why do you assume using pointers would make this more efficient?

Comment: Your first version does nothing - you swap (a,b) forward to (b,a) and then again backwards from (b,a) to (a,b).

Answer (score 1):

My favourite trick for this is to not move anything at all.

Store a flag in your structure for whether you access by rows or columns fist, and change your get/set to respect that. Then transposing is just flipping that flag.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with a white board or a clean sheet of paper. Draw boxes for your memory pointers, and draw out your matrix. Draw arrows from your memory boxes to the cell locations that your pointers are referencing.

Once you do that, you should be able to find your bug very easily.

For example, if you have the following code:

```
int* row = A[i];
```

Draw your A matrix with its rows and columns, then draw a separate box and label it "row". Draw an arrow from the box to the A[0] row since row will first point to the 0th row.

Always have a drawing surface handy when working with pointers and references!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems on both of your codes.

**First one:**

- As [drahnr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715762/creating-a-more-efficient-matrix-transpose-code-in-c#comment32838004_21715762) also pointed out, a swap is issued twice per cell for every cell except for the ones that have `i == j`. The ones with `i == j` get no swapping at all and the others get swapped twice, essentially doing nothing.

**Second one:**

- t1 variable entirely unused.
- You get beyond the boundaries that your array covers for all `2i >= M`, accessing a memory area that you should be messing around with.

Look:

```
int t2 = *(col + M*i)+(i*4);
```

is exactly the same as:

```
int t2 = A[i + i][j] + (i*4);
```

With the second `i` coming from your `+ M*i`. In words:

- `col` was indicating the cell `[i][j]`,
- then you wanted the cell that is `M * i` after that.
- each `M` cell further, brings you to the next column (or row, whichever way you had imagined it on your mind, doesn't matter)
- so, `M * i` will mean `i` column/row further

And `A[2i][j]` will be beyond the upper limit `M` that you shouldn't be exceeding for `2i >= M`.

That `+ (i*4)` doesn't make any effects over the cell being used, because of the [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). Dereferencing operators `*` get evaluated before additions, requiring you to use parentheses in case you want addition to happen earlier; but in this case, things wouldn't get better even if you used them.

This kind of approach wouldn't optimize the process any further anyway. [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716082/2736228)'s way would be interesting and probably the fastest. But you could just fix the first code to work properly (i.e. not swap twice), and also not to issue a swap for `i == j` and that should be good enough. I won't tell you how to do that, you surely will be able to do it.

I can give you one hint for swapping though... Instead of:

```
  int t = A[i][j];
  A[i][j] = A[j][i];
  A[j][i] = t;
```

one could write:

```
  A[i][j] ^= A[j][i];
  A[j][i] ^= A[i][j];
  A[i][j] ^= A[j][i];
```

which also would do the swapping, without requiring a carrier. I don't know if it would optimize the process much, but yeah, just a fun trick.